# Scale ion icon SVG to div dimensions

Tags: css, svg

How can a scale this perfect circle svg to the width of the div and keep in the center - and no repeat it. It is placed as a background image:

```
<style>
.play_full{
background: url('../_svg/_ionicons_svg_md-play-circle.svg');
position:absolute;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

This is what I am getting now?
[image]

How can I center the svg V and H?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use flexbox position to center, I changed this:

- use `Flexbox` to centering elements in `.cotainer`
- added `width` and `height` on `.play_full`

```css
.container {
  border : 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.play-full {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="play-full"></div>
</div>
```